# UITextView filling entire frame

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextview, nui

I assume this is related to NUI, which I've just started implementing. I've just placed a UITextView into my view with Interface Builder, but when I go into the simulator, it simply fills the entire view with the text box.

Any ideas why this may be?

**View controller in Interface Builder**

[image: View controller in Interface Builder]

**View controller in iPhone Simulator**

[image: View controller in Simulator]

Comment: What happens if NUI is disabled?  Are you using autolayout?  Have you set up the autoresizing mask?  Do you have screenshots of IB versus actual?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the issue?

Comment: Does the same if NUI is disabled. I'm not using autolayout and autosizing is left as default. It's basically a untouched brand new view, so I'm really puzzled as to what's going on...

Comment: Here's an [IB screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144706/textview1.png) vs [simulator screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144706/textview2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the behavior you're seeing on the simulator.

If you select your text field in the IB and look at its outlets, you should see something like the below where it has a Referencing Outlet to the view controller's `view` property.

When the view controller is being loaded this relationship forces the text field to take up the whole screen.  Deleting the referencing outlet should cause the screen to display correctly.

[image]

Comment: Oh dear how embarrasing! You're absolutely right, that's what I had done. I blame a slip of the mouse... Thank you, and very good detective work!